# Testing app on iOS6 and iOS 7 - UPDATED

Tags: ios6, ios7

I need to test my app on both `iOS 6` and `iOS 7`. Here's what i have done so far: I have developed an app on iOS 7, but i need to support iOS 6 too.

But because i need to follow slightly different layout for `iOS 6` and `iOS 7`, i am making separate xibs for both. I have tested the app for iOS 7, and now i need to do it for iOS 6.

I have downloaded `iOS 6 simulator` already. Note that i don't have a real `iOS 6` device, i have only `iOS 7` device. Now please tell me how do i test it on iOS 6 and how to i detect programmatically which `iOS version` my phone is running.

In the code, I need to check the version of the `iOS` that the device is using, and then load the `xibs` accordingly.

This is the code that i am using to do that.

```
float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (sysVer >= 7.0)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is ios 7");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"this is ios 6");
    }
```

I am currently testing it on my `iPhone 5` that has `iOS 7` on it.

So, i have tested my app on `iOS 7`, but when testing it on `iOS 6` (by choosing "`deployment target`" as `iOS 6` in `target settings` and `project settings`) , i am still seeing on console - `this is ios 7`.

However, the keyboard appearance is `iOS6-like`..!!

Why is this happening?? why am i not able to check the iOS version???

Comment: Well if you are running on an iOS 7 device or simulator of course it will still show as iOS7. Start using an iOS 6 device or simulator.

Comment: If you compile with iOS7 SDK(Xcode 5), then your app will automatically have and iOS7 like keyboard on iOS7.
But the keyboard ha nothing to do with your if statement, which is correct

Answer (score 1):

Deployment target and system version aren't the same.

Basically, you're running an app compiled for iOS 6 on an iOS 7 simulator. That's why it reports a version of 7, and uses the style of iOS 6.

You need to run your app on a simulated iOS 6 by choosing it from the target dropdown at the top left of Xcode:

[image]

(Maybe you haven't downloaded the simulators for iOS 6, first check Xcode preferences).

Or better yet, on an actual iOS 6 device.

Anyway, if you intend to use the native iOS 7 look on iOS 7 devices, never lower the deployment target to 6. Keep it at 7.

Comment: i have downloaded iOS 6 simulator already. And i am not running the app on simulator, i am running it on iPhone 5. I don't have an iOS 6 device.

Comment: Then you're running on iOS 7, and have compiled your app for iOS 6 only. No wonder it shows the iOS 6 keyboard, that's intended behaviour introduced by Apple for upwards compatibility. You need to do the reverse: compile your app with a deployment target of iOS 7, and test it on a real iOS 6 device, or a simulator.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Here's what i have done so far: I have developed an app on iOS 7, but i need to support iOS 6 too. But because i need to follow slightly different layout for iOS 6 and iOS 7, i am making separate xibs for both. I have tested the app for iOS 7, and now i need to do it for iOS 6. I have downloaded iOS 6 simulator already. Note that i don't have a real iOS 6 device, i have only iOS 7 device. Now please tell me how do i test it on iOS 6 and how to i detect programmatically which iOS version my phone is running.

Comment: @Coder123 if you have set your iOS deployment target to iOS 6.0 the minimum iOS your apps supports will be iOS 6.0. Since you don't have a device with iOS 6 on it you will need to use the simulator. If you run your app on iOS 7 device it will run with iOS 7 look and feel whilst if you run it on iOS 6 device it will have the old iOS 6 look and feel. If you have downloaded the simulator like your comments states you should be able to select the device and iOS just like in the image on this answer. If iOS 6 doesn't appear in there you have either not downloaded it or deployment target is wrong.